# Ubuntu Installation - "ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: cannot execute binary file" on Mac

Tags: system-installation, mac

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.1 on mac and I was able to download Ubuntu Desktop file `ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`. The issue happens when I try to install this.  As per the installation instruction, I went to the terminal on Mac and sudo bash and dragged the file to the terminal but getting the following error:

```
/Users/xxxxx/Downloads/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: cannot execute binary file
```

I followed the exact steps provided in YouTube videos and installation instructions. Am I missing something or is this permission related issue?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What instructions told you to do that?! The ISO is not executable. You have to burn it to USB or DVD and boot from it

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but I don't have enough reputation for comment:

You can not execute an iso file like that. Follow the instructions on this site to create a bootable Ubuntu USB from the iso file:

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0